# Color some faces differently

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I am trying to render a mesh using OpenGL and then render its boundary faces in a different color. I'm comming from DirectX so I don't have much of an idea of what I'm doing, but so far it's been slightly frustrating.

Below is my code, which doesn't seem to render the borders at all. I have also tried disabling lighting and few other things of which none have worked.

```
void RendererWidget::drawModel()
{
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    drawMeshFaceted(m_model->getMesh());

    drawMeshBorder(m_model->getMesh());
}

void RendererWidget::drawMeshFaceted(const MyMesh *m)
{
    MyMesh::ConstFaceIter fIt(m->faces_begin());
    MyMesh::ConstFaceIter fEnd(m->faces_end());
    MyMesh::ConstFaceVertexIter fvIt;

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (; fIt != fEnd; ++fIt)
    {
        glNormal3fv( &m->normal(*fIt)[0]);

        fvIt = m->cfv_iter(*fIt);
        glVertex3fv( &m->point(*fvIt)[0] );
        ++fvIt;
        glVertex3fv( &m->point(*fvIt)[0] );
        ++fvIt;
        glVertex3fv( &m->point(*fvIt)[0] );
    }
    glEnd();
}

void RendererWidget::drawMeshBorder(const MyMesh *m)
{
    MyMesh::ConstFaceIter fIt(m->faces_begin());
    MyMesh::ConstFaceIter fEnd(m->faces_end());
    MyMesh::ConstFaceVertexIter fvIt;

    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (; fIt != fEnd; ++fIt)
    {
        if (m->is_boundary(*fIt))
        {
            glNormal3fv( &m->normal(*fIt)[0]);

            fvIt = m->cfv_iter(*fIt);
            glVertex3fv( &m->point(*fvIt)[0] );
            ++fvIt;
            glVertex3fv( &m->point(*fvIt)[0] );
            ++fvIt;
            glVertex3fv( &m->point(*fvIt)[0] );
        }
    }
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
}
```

If I call any of the above methods separately they work just fine. I assume it is something simple I'm missing.

Comment: please look up how to use the newer style openGL

Comment: I'll definitely do. For now though, I assume it is possible to achieve what I want with the above style.

Comment: If the routines above draw fine separately, then it's likely that there's some state that's changing between the calls. You also haven't specified any values for the material. The docs say you must call `glColorMaterial()` before enabling `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`. What other state are you changing in your program?

Comment: Are the two sets of triangles mutually exclusive? If the border triangles drawn in drawMeshBorder are also included in drawMeshFaceted, with depth testing enabled, they will not be rendered unless glDeptFunc is set to GL_LEQUAL.

Comment: I managed to fix it for now, by calling `drawMeshBorder()` before `drawMeshFaceted()` and adding another glColor3f statement in between the functions, so that the mesh is drawn with different color. That'll do for now, until I learn the proper ways of modern OpenGL.

Comment: I think Pondwater is right ... you draw to same pixels (at same X,Y,Z-coordinates) which Z-Buffer discards until you set compare condition to <= or >= instead of < or  >. Also what about to use lines for border ? (of course if you have bigger border width then that is not a good idea)

Comment: Yes, lines are what I'll eventually want to draw for now I was just checking if me border detection works. I guess the question is then how to draw selected face edges in a different colour than faces themselves.